# HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods Enabled vulnerability in Coldfusion server

Tags: coldfusion, http-trace

I keep getting HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods Enabled vulnerability in Coldfusion server. Any suggestions to fix this would be of great help.

Comment: If you do not use those methods then disable them. Just Google for something like `disable HTTP TRACE / TRACK Methods`.

Answer (score 0):

The blanket disallowing of these methods is more the concern of the HTTP server (IIS, Apache, NGINX ) than the application server (Coldfusion, Lucee). There may be use cases where these HTTP verbs might be legitimately in use.

You can, however, handle this from within the `onRequestStart` method of `Application.cfc` with a few lines of code.

```
var disallowVerbs = [ "TRACE", "TRACK" ];
if( arrayContains( disallowVerbs, cgi.request_method ) ){
    cfheader( statusCode=403, statusText="Method Not Allowed" );
}
```